# JS decorator return original method if check succeeds

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator, ecmascript-next

I've setup a simple decorator for my graphql mutations, all it's supposed todo is run an auth check on the request to see if it's authorised or not. I've got it to run the check & return an error if everything goes to plan, but when there is no error (request is authorised), it just hangs.

Here is my decorator code:

```
function checkAuth(target) {
  target.mutateAndGetPayload = (input, { rootValue }) => {
    if (!rootValue.request.user) {
      return {
        error: {
          message: `Invalid authorization header`,
          type: "invalid_auth",
          client_message: `You do not have permission to access this resource`,
        }
      };
    }

    return target.mutateAndGetPayload;
  };
  return target;
}
```

And here is my mutation code (just a simple mutation):

```
const AddMedicalRecord = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'AddMedicalRecord',
  description: 'AddMedicalRecord',
  inputFields: {
    ...fields here...
  },
  outputFields: {
    error: {
      type: ErrorType, // Simply: { client_message, message, type }
      description: 'Description of the error if anything',
      resolve: payload => payload.error
    },
    success: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'Description of the success',
      resolve: payload => payload.success
    }
  },
  @checkAuth
  mutateAndGetPayload: (input, { rootValue }) => {
    console.log(input, 'passed decorator :D ') // It never reaches here with decorator
```

It never reaches that console.log IF the request is authorized and the decorator does not return an error. Any help is appreciated as I've only used decorators a handful of times. I feel like it's something todo with the way I'm returning inside the `target.mutateAndGetPayload`

Comment: Just FYI, decorators are not part of ES6. They are a proposal, i.e. not part of any specification yet.

Comment: @FelixKling Cool thanks for letting me know!